# if url hash = article id, change css of this id

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

here is my situation:
i'm using WD Gridfolio on my website, this way on the collection page, people can click and see the content being display without showing a new Url.

---UPDATE---

I Got it work via:

```
    if(window.location.hash) {
 var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
$("#"+hash).find(".wmg-thumbnail2").trigger("click")
}
```

--END UPDATE---

Works Great.

However, I can't give a link to the item "open".

http://domain.com/mycollection

On this page all the item are display, I would like - when the user click on one item, the url to become

http://domain.com/mycollection/item1 or http://domain.com/mycollection#item1

This, to be able to give this url to different user, this way is people go to this link, they should arrive to the page with the item "open".

from this I've been trying to make work a javascript like if hash = article ID, then add a class and Css on this article ID to have it open.

I've try something like:

```
$('.wmg-container2').find('.wmg-item2').each(function(){
if ($(this).parent().attr('#article-{id}') == hash) {
    $add.class('open');
}
});
```

Without sucess...

The path shoudl take somethign similar as:

```
if (window.location.hash){
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  if (hash == "#article-{id}"){
     openFeedbackForm();


 $onclick('.wmg-item2'+ "#article-{id}"){
 add.class('.open')
};
 (.'wmg-details');
change.css('overflow','visible')
  }
   }
```

( yes there is a lot of mistake in this last code - it 's just to make understand the path)

Any idea how this can be realise ??

Below is the structure of my page:

```
 <div class="wmg-container2 my-grid2">
     {.repeated section items}
     <div class="wmg-item2" data-item-id="{id}" id="article-{id}">
         <div class="wmg-thumbnail2">
             <div class="wmg-thumbnail-content2">
                 <!-- exemplo de conteudo para thumbnail -->
                 {.main-image?} <img data-image-dimensions="{originalSize}"
                 src="{fullUrl}?format=2500w"> {.end} 
                 <!-- fim do exemplo -->
             </div>
             <div class="all-overlay">
                 <div class="meta-overlay">
                     {.section categories}
                     <div>
                         <em>{.equal? collection.typeName
                         "products"}Found{.or}{.end}</em> {.repeated section
                         @}<a href=
                         "{collection.fullUrl}?category={@|url-encode}" rel=
                         "tag" style=
                         "float:none;color:white;width:100%;left:20px;position:absolute;top:7px;text-transform:uppercase">{@}</a>{.alternates
                         with}, {.end}
                     </div>{.end} {.if categories && tags} <em></em> {.end}
                 </div>
                 <div class="title-overlay">
                     {title}
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="wmg-details2">
             <div class="wmg-details-content2">
                 <!-- exemplo de coteúdo para detail -->
                 <div class="container2 exemplo2">
                     {body}
                 </div><!-- fim do exemplo -->
             </div><span class="wmg-close2"></span>
         </div>
     </div>{.end} {.end}
 </div>
```

Really appreciate all your time / help / advise on that !

Comment: You already asked your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976501/url-hastag-to-have-item-open-from-portfolio-grid . Please don't submit duplicate entries rather update the old question.

Comment: these links are not working

Comment: Take a look at the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class.

Comment: I've delte the old post - thanks.

Linsk are not working as im not allow to show the real website

Gonna look at :target thanks

Comment: Can't deal with target ass I need to add a class to the article id aswell, all is old by js . .. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<a href='#item1'>` and that will change the url to http://domain.com/mycollection/#item1

Comment: it's a dynamic website - squarespace so I can't do that, but thank you

Comment: without seeing you code i don't know what else to tell you ;)

Comment: Yes I understand but I really can't, I 've added the original code of the page in the post if it helps :)